# Who can edit the help pages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

Can we add don't post pictures of code/output/arrays etc. to the 'how to ask' page?

I just recently linked to this page due to a question including what I first thought was only two images (but as links), and I noticed the how to ask does not say anything about pictures of code/text etc.

Comment: Only [CM's can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281485/158100) after a meta post. So if this post is going to be that request, include the copy that needs to be added/ changed so mods only have to forward the request with a link to this very question. (or write an answer with the proposed version so we can vote on that)

Comment: As my native language is not English I think someone else is better suited to do the actual wording. But in essence, don't post pictures of what is text.

Comment: @
Andreas
 well English is my native language and I don't think I could word it better than you.  This is a good idea.